# cron import more than 2 files with feeds

Tags: feeds, cron

I'm on Drupal 7 using services and feeds. We have 10 XML files we're trying to upload during cron that doesn't work.
If I do it manually by using wget/cURL via SSH only 2 files are uploaded. If I run  cron 1 min later, only the two XML files are uploaded.
Where can I set cron to upload more than 2 XML files during the feeds cron job?